# Android: Want to call main activity's class function in service class

Tags: android

Here I have a main class that extends activity and having a function say abc(). Now I want to call it in my services class. But I am unable to do that plz some one help as I found error : "Source not found"..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow community. Please do practice of asking question with details like **code/effort** you have tried, **logcat output** if you are getting any exception, problem snaps....

Comment: public class Abc extends Activity { public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Android: How to Call Function of Activity from a Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843874/in-android-how-to-call-function-of-activity-from-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the related Topics/Questions have already solved your problem, e.g.

[In Android: How to Call Function of Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843874/in-android-how-to-call-function-of-activity-from-a-service?rq=1)

[Call a Method in the main activity from a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435248/call-a-method-in-the-main-activity-from-a-custom-view-class?rq=1)

[How to call An activity class from a service class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015507/how-to-call-an-activity-class-from-a-service-class?rq=1)